# groovy define metaclass with its own custom methods and set it for the object

Tags: groovy, metaclass

Is it possible to set `metaclass` for the object in `groovy` with its custom methods? I mean something like some kind of dynamic inheritance...

For example something like this

```
class Original {
    def my_method() { }
}

class Meta {
    def meta_method() { }
}

def obj = new Original()
obj.metaClass = new Meta()

obj.meta_method()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use traits to achieve this kind of things. It's a little more "high level" than directly manipuling the metaclass

```
​class Original {
  def my_method() { } 
}  

trait Meta {
  def meta_method() { } 
}  

def obj = new Original()​.withTraits Meta
​obj.meta_method()​
```

see: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html#_implementing_a_trait_at_runtime